# Resetting value of editText after each change

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I want the value of `editText` to be set to null after the line: `new nwcomm.execute(cmd,cmd1)` so that I can send keys as I press them on the keyboard. I tried `keyboard.setText(null);` but it doesn't work. What should I do?

```
keyboard.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String stt="key_";
        String key=keyboard.getText().toString();
        String cmd=stt+key;
        new nwcomm().execute(cmd,cmd1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't `setText("")` work? There is the problem that it will call `ontextChanged()` again but a simple if statement can prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [afterTextChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged%28android.text.Editable%29) instead of `onTextChanged` per the documentation I linked.  That should fix your problem with clearing the `TextView`; however, you have to be careful not to get into an infinite loop doing this.  You'll have to add a check for empty string such as

```
keyboard.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String key = s.toString();
        if ( key.isEmpty() )
            return;
        String stt="key_";
        String cmd=stt+key;
        new nwcomm().execute(cmd,cmd1);
        s.clear();
}
```

That should to the trick.

Comment: Edited my answer significantly.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you want to reset the edittext value, use editText.setText("");

Comment: This is identical to Ralgha's original answer, to quote Niraj's response "nope tried that too..."